# Помогите понять что означает ошибка и как ее исправить

Tags: python, python-3.x

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\PythonApplication8\PythonApplication8.py", line 158, in 
main()

File "C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\PythonApplication8\PythonApplication8.py", line 152, in main
move = computer_move(board, computer, human)

TypeError: computer_move() takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .

```
    #глобальные константы
X = "X"
O = "O"
EMPTY = " "
TIE = "Ничья"
NUM_SQUARES = 9

def display_instruct():
    """Выводит инструкцию для игрока"""
    print(
    """
    Добро пожаловать.
    Чтобы сделать ход, введи число от 0 до 8. Числа соответствуют полям доски - так, как показано ниже:
    0 1 2
    3 4 5
    6 7 8
    \n"""
    )
    
def ask_yes_no(question):
    """Задает вопрос с овтетом да или нет"""
    response = None
    while response not in ("y", "n"):
        response = input(question).lower()
    return response

def ask_number(question, low, high):
    """Просит ввести число из диапазона"""
    response = None
    while response not in (question, low, high):
        response = int(input(question))
    return response

def pieces():
    """Определяет принадлежность первоо хода"""
    go_first = ask_yes_no("Хочешь оставить за собой первый ход? (y/n): ")
    if go_first == "y":
        print("\nДаю тебе фору, играй крестиками")
        human = X
        computer = O
    else:
        print("Начинать будет комп")
        human = X
        computer = O
    return computer, human

def new_board():
    """Создает новую доску"""
    board = []
    for sqare in range(NUM_SQUARES):
        board.append(EMPTY)
    return board

def display_board(board):
    """Отображает игровую доску на экране"""
    print("\n\t", board[0], "|", board[1], "|", board[2])
    print("\t___________")
    print("\n\t", board[3], "|", board[4], "|", board[5])
    print("\t___________")
    print("\n\t", board[6], "|", board[7], "|", board[8],   "\n")
    
def legal_moves(board):
    """Создает список доступных ходов"""
    moves = []
    for sqare in range(NUM_SQUARES):
        if board[sqare] == EMPTY:
            moves.append(sqare)
    return moves

def winner(board):
    """Определяет победителя в игре"""
    WAYS_TO_WIN = ((0, 1, 2),
                    (3, 4, 5),
                    (6, 7, 8),
                    (0, 3, 6),
                    (1, 4, 7),
                    (2, 5, 8),
                    (0, 4, 8),
                    (2, 4, 6))
    for row in WAYS_TO_WIN:
        if board[row[0]] == board[row[1]] == board[row[2]] != EMPTY:
            winner = board[row[0]]
            return winner
        if EMPTY not in board:
            return TIE
    return None

def human_move(board, human):
    """Получает ход человека"""
    legal = legal_moves(board)
    move = None
    while move not in legal:
        move = ask_number("Твой ход. Выбери одно из полей (0 - 8):", 0, NUM_SQUARES)
        if move not in legal:
            print("\nВыбери другое")
    print("Ладно")
    return move

def computer_move():
    """Делает ход за компьютерного противника"""
    board = board[:]
    BEST_MOVES = (4, 0, 2, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7)
    print("Я выберу номер", end=" ")
    for move in legal_moves(board):
        board[move] = computer
        if winner(board) == computer:
            print(move)
            return move
        board[move] = EMPTY
    for move in legal_moves(board):
        board[move] = human
        if winner(board) == human:
            print(move)
            return move
        board[move] = EMPTY
    for move in BEST_MOVES:
        if move in legal_moves(board):
            print(move)
            return move

def next_turn(turn):
    """Осуществляет переход хода"""
    if turn == X:
        return 0
    else:
        return X

def congratat_winner(the_winner, computer, human):
    """Поздравляем победителя игры"""
    if the_winner != TIE:
        print("Три", the_winner, "В ряд\n")
    else:
        print("Ничья!\n")
    if the_winner == computer:
        print("Победа за мной")
    elif the_winner == human:
        print("Человек победил")
    elif the_winner == TIE:
        print("Ничья")

def main():
    display_instruct()
    computer, human = pieces()
    turn = X
    board = new_board()
    display_board(board)
    while not winner(board):
        if turn == human:
            move = human_move(board, human)
            board[move] = human
        else:
            move = computer_move(board, computer, human)
            board[move] = computer
        display_board(board)
        turn = next_turn(turn)
    the_winner = winner(board)
    congrat_winner(the_winner, computer, human)
main()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот ваш код, в котором вызывается функция `computer_move`:

```
    if turn == human:
        move = human_move(board, human)
        board[move] = human
    else:
        move = computer_move(board, computer, human)
        print(move)
        board[move] = computer
```

а вот описание самой функции:

```
def computer_move():
```

Вы передаете 3 параметра и не используйте ни одного!

И сама ошибка вам про это же пишет!

```
TypeError: computer_move() takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given
```